# How to setup load balancing with Azure Traffic Manager for Multiple websites?

Tags: azure

Is it possible to have multiple websites load balanced with traffic manager on say 2 or more webserver vm's in Azure? and if so, how does traffic manager get setup so that it can monitor each website service as opposed to the server itself?

It seems like it can only monitor the port on the webserver, so this implies that traffic manager will only work if one website is running on each webserver.

Can someone clear this up for me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by webserver.  Windows Azure Traffic Manager (WATM) is intended for 2 different deployments in 2 different datacenters.  Using WATM you can achieve your goal.  The setup would be like:

www.myapp1.com -> myapp1.trafficmanager.net -> {endpoints in multiple datacenters}:{port for myapp1 health probe} 
 
www.myapp2.com -> myapp2.trafficmanager.net -> {the same endpoints as myapp1}:{port for myapp2 health probe}

However, if you are referring to 2 webservers as in 2 different VMs in the same datacenter then you would just add them both to load balancer set and configure the LB probes for each site.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, one last question, If I am using WATM or the regular LD method how does either one monitor the service of the website itself because I am running 10 different websites on both of the 2 webservers. Example website1 is running on both webservers, website2 is running on both webservers, ect... it looks like WATM or LB just monitors the webserver and not if the website is up or not. Do I have this right? is this a limitation?